# Unable to load pictures from PhotoLibrary Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I am totally newbie to Swift , I don't get any error and my app compliles fine. however I am unable to load any photos , can someone point me to the correct direction

here is my code from the storyboard

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  FoodTester
//
//  Created by Waheed Rafiq on 11/10/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Waheed Rafiq. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
// Object inhertance to in IOS you adopt the protocol same theory
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate ,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate{


// MARK: Properties


@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!


// MARK : UITextFieldDelegate ---> 





// MARK: Actions below --->

@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary
(_ sender:   UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    // hide the keyboard
    nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    //UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets user pick   media from their photo library.

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    // only allow photos to be picket not taken.
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }

// need to implement two of the delegate methods defined in.

// MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel
(_ picker: UIImagePickerController)   {
    // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController
(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    // the info dictionary contrains 
 multiple representations of the image and this uses the original.

 let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] 
 as!   UIImage

    // Set PhotoImageView to display the selected image.

    photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker
    dismiss(animated:true,completion:nil)
}


@IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(_ sender: UIButton) {

    mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"
    nameTextField.text = "Enter something"

}

// Mark: Gesture recognizer 


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after 
 loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // handle the text fields user input throught delegate callbacks.
    nameTextField.delegate = self


}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // hide the keyboard
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true


}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    mealNameLabel.text = textField.text


   }

}
```

any mistake any advice is greatly appericated

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for swift 3.0,

```
@IBAction func selectPhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]
    self.imageView!.image! = chosenImage
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to click the checkbox that says "User Interaction Enabled" in the Attributes Editor for the Image View. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHDj0.png). Essentially, this error comes from missing instruction #12 in the "Add a Meal Photo" section:

> In the Attributes inspector, find the Interaction field and select the
>   User Interaction Enabled checkbox.   You’ll need this feature later to
>   let users interact with the image view.